# Interacting with buttons in a panel using Python - Selenium/Chrome Driver

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I need to click on a button in a pop-up panel, select an option from its drop-down menu, read that option's text (just an asset ID), and then select a button to Generate a report. For some reason, I am able to access the panel's text area to input my custom file name, but cannot interact with the buttons. An image of the panel in question is linked below for reference.

The text area's XPATH:

```
/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/form/div/md-content/md-tabs/md-tabs-content-wrapper/md-tab-content[2]/div/md-content/div[2]/textarea
```

The code that will access the text area, clear the default name, and send the new file name:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/form/div/md-content/md-tabs/md-tabs-content-wrapper/md-tab-content[2]/div/md-content/div[2]/textarea'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/form/div/md-content/md-tabs/md-tabs-content-wrapper/md-tab-content[2]/div/md-content/div[2]/textarea'))).clear()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/form/div/md-content/md-tabs/md-tabs-content-wrapper/md-tab-content[2]/div/md-content/div[2]/textarea'))).send_keys(file_name)
```

The "Generate" button's XPATH:

```
/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/form/div/md-content/md-tabs/md-tabs-content-wrapper/md-tab-content[2]/div/md-content/div[1]/md-menu-bar/md-menu/button
```

The code unable to click the "Generate" button:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/button[1]'))).click()
```

The pop-up panel's XPATH:

```
/html/body/div[4]/div[2]
```

Any and all help is appreciated, thank you!

[Panel I am interacting with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw1lz.png)

Comment: Can you confirm the page url? Those xpaths make my eyes hurt.

Comment: text area: //*[@id="fileName"], generate button: //*[@id="Download"]/div/button[1] ... the dashboard page itself is behind a login for a predictive maintenance software. hopefully this helps

Comment: SOrry, I'm still lost. Best I can do in this situation (where you cannot provide the url, not the full html for that page,  is to give you a couple of pointers: 1 - try and wait for the elements to be clickable prior to interacting with them, and 2 - make sure there isn;t any iframe, or shadow root enveloping those elements. Selenium docs can be found at https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/

Comment: Thank you, I'll be sure to check the documentation

Comment: Oh - and try and locate them using more robust locators: class/other attributes, or text/partial text. It's all in the documentation.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Is it that the element is not clickable or that it is not finding the element?

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: @jloar Why did you delete your comment saying that the answer worked rather than just marking the answer as correct? Just press the tick by the voting buttons next to the answer if the answer solved your problem.

Comment: @MarcusWilliams it will not allow me to as i have less than 15 reputation. at least that's what the site pop-up said

Comment: I believe there is no minimum requirements for accepting an answer to your question. What you must be trying to do is upvote (which requires 15 reputation). Instead press the tick symbol below the voting buttons if you want to accept the answer, this will also give you reputation. This may help https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error is that the element is not clickable, but it is being found you can try this.

```
#Wait until the element is loaded
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/button[1]')))

#find the element, assuming your webdriver is called driver (change the 'driver' part below if not)
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/button[1]')

#click the button with a script, again assuming the webdriver name
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', button)
```

This works by using JavaScript to click the button element rather than the button needing to be clickable at a given position.

If your problem was that the button was not clickable, that may help solve it. Sorry if this didn't help.